# Json Key_value to stdout using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, subprocess

I'm new to python scripting .I'm trying to parse a json key_value to stdout. Below is my script.Help me out in fixing below error.

```
    pt="{'outval': 1.132805, 'max': 1.13283, 'to': 1534326908, 'bvalue': 1.13274, 'min': 1.132805, 'from': 1534326907, 'cvalue': 1.132825, 'at': 1534326907164488223, 'avalue': 1.13291, 'size': 1, 'aid': 1, 'vl': 0, 'id': 17777726}"

    print(pt["outval"])
    print(pt["to"])
    print(pt["from"])
```

Error :

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "j.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(pt["outval"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Expected output:

```
1.132805
1534326908
1534326907
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at doing `json.loads(pt)` so that you get a `dict` rather than just a string?

Comment: Thanks Guys, Converted it to dict .Now  i got required result .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Jon for the idea. I used ast.literal_eval to extract required key pair.Below is my updated code.

```
import json
import ast

pt="{'outval': 1.132805, 'max': 1.13283, 'to': 1534326908, 'bvalue': 1.13274, 'min': 1.132805, 'from': 1534326907, 'cvalue': 1.132825, 'at': 1534326907164488223, 'avalue': 1.13291, 'size': 1, 'aid': 1, 'vl': 0, 'id': 17777726}"

s=ast.literal_eval(pt)
print(s['outval'])
print(s['to'])
print(s['from'])
```

output :

```
root@lamp-1-vm:~/1# python j.py
1.132805
1534326908
1534326907
```

Comment: As you presumably noticed, the original string is not valid JSON. If the process that produces that string is something you can control, you will want to look at changing that to use `json.dump`/`json.dumps` instead of writing `str(dict)`

Comment: Ahhh yes... I completely glanced over the fact you had `'`s and not `"`s JSON style... :)